# Worker names for DynamicSupervisors

Tags: elixir

Heeey all,

I'm kinda new to elixir and quite lost with setting worker names and id's for workers in elixir and I hope that someone can help me out a bit.

My Application file

```
defmodule Squareup.Application do
  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      # Starts a worker by calling: Squareup.Worker.start_link(arg)
      # {Squareup.Worker, arg}
      Journey,
      Squareup.JourneySupervisor,
      {Squareup.DynamicJourneySupervisor, strategy: :one_for_one, name: Squareup.DynamicJourneySupervisor}
    ]

    # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Squareup.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

So I startup 2 supervisors a regular one and a dynamic one:

The regular one:

```
defmodule Squareup.JourneySupervisor do

  use Supervisor

  def start_link(opts) do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, opts, name: :my_test_123)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(_init_arg) do
    children = [
      # Starts a worker by calling: Squareup.Worker.start_link(arg)
      # {Squareup.Worker, arg}
      {Queue, [:child_one]},
      {Queue, [:child_two]},
    ]
    Supervisor.init(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end

  def child_spec(opts) do
    %{
      id: :my_test_123s,
      start: {__MODULE__, :start_link, [opts]},
      shutdown: 5_000,
      restart: :permanent,
      type: :supervisor
    }
  end
end
```

The Dynamic One:

```
defmodule Squareup.DynamicJourneySupervisor do
  use DynamicSupervisor

  def start_link(init_arg) do
    DynamicSupervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, init_arg, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def start_child(init_args) do
    # If MyWorker is not using the new child specs, we need to pass a map:
    # spec = %{id: MyWorker, start: {MyWorker, :start_link, [foo, bar, baz]}}
    spec = {Queue, init_args}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(init_arg) do
    DynamicSupervisor.init(strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

The normal supervisor a module called `Queue`

```
defmodule Queue do
  require Logger
  use GenServer

  ### GenServer API
  def init(state), do: {:ok, state}
  def handle_call(:dequeue, _from, [value | state]) do {:reply, value, state} end
  def handle_call(:dequeue, _from, []), do: {:reply, nil, []}
  def handle_call(:queue, _from, state), do: {:reply, state, state}
  def handle_cast({:enqueue, value}, state) do {:noreply, state ++ [value]} end

  ### Client API / Helper functions

  def start_link(state \\ []) do
    Logger.info("Initializing queue with state:")
    Logger.info(inspect(state))
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state, name: List.first(state))
  end

  def child_spec(opts) do
    Logger.info("Initializing child_spec:")
    Logger.info(inspect(opts))
    %{
      id: List.first(opts),
      start: {__MODULE__, :start_link, [opts]},
      shutdown: 5_000,
      restart: :permanent,
      type: :worker
    }
  end

  def queue, do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :queue)
  def enqueue(value), do: GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:enqueue, value})
  def dequeue, do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :dequeue)
end
```

When I start the application I this:

```
12:55:45.744 [info]  Initializing child_spec:
12:55:45.749 [info]  [:child_one]
12:55:45.749 [info]  Initializing child_spec:
12:55:45.749 [info]  [:child_two]
12:55:45.749 [info]  Initializing queue with state:
12:55:45.749 [info]  [:child_one]
12:55:45.749 [info]  Initializing queue with state:
12:55:45.749 [info]  [:child_two]

iex(4)> Supervisor.which_children(:my_test_123)
[
  {:child_two, #PID<0.218.0>, :worker, [Queue]},
  {:child_one, #PID<0.217.0>, :worker, [Queue]}
]
```

But when I tell the Dynamic Supervisor to startup the process

```
Squareup.DynamicJourneySupervisor.start_child([:my_dyname])
12:56:07.329 [info]  Initializing child_spec:
12:56:07.329 [info]  [:my_dyname]
12:56:07.330 [info]  Initializing queue with state:
12:56:07.330 [info]  [:my_dyname]
```

and look up the worker names, then they are always `:undefined`

```
iex(5)> Supervisor.which_children(Squareup.DynamicJourneySupervisor)
[{:undefined, #PID<0.224.0>, :worker, [Queue]}]
```

The id of the worker seems to be set correctly. Is there a way to set the name when a process is started via the DynamicSupervisor?

Already many thanks in advance!

Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just misinterpreted the returned values from `which_children/1` function. It returns a list with information about all children actually.

From the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html#which_children/1):

```
* id - it is always :undefined for dynamic supervisors
```

Hence you are actually naming your processes correctly. Just your client code for `Queue` module is incorrect. You should fix your functions `queue` `enqueue` and `dequeue` to actually call a named GenServer if you want to access those.

What I mean is they should look like this for example:

```
  def queue(name \\ __MODULE__), do: GenServer.call(name, :queue)
  def enqueue(name \\ __MODULE__, value), do: GenServer.cast(name, {:enqueue, value})
  def dequeue(name \\ __MODULE__), do: GenServer.call(name, :dequeue)
```

This way `GenServer.call/2` will always call the named GenServers. You can also access them not by the names but by their `pids` (which you can actually receive from `which_children/1` function dynamically if you need).

Comment: Yeah you're right silly me. it indeed just in the docs. Thanks a lot and also thanks a lot for the   Queue module fix!